# What's wrong in this c function?

Tags: c, function

This is to be used to give an int variable a value of 26 if the original value is -33 and value of 27 if the original value is -19

```
void func(int *a)
{

    if (a == -33)
        *a = 26;

    if (*a == -19)
        *a = 27;
}
```

Comment: use this : `if (*a == -33)`

Comment: Can't you yourself observe the differences in both if-statements pattern,to be the least! Please don't copy code without understanding,if you're doing so...

Answer (score 3):

Let's take a closer look at the first if statement:

```
if (a == -33)
    *a = 26;
```

The `a == -33` is the issue. Remember, `a` is of type `int*`. So, you're not checking if `a` has the value -33; you're checking if the *address* pointed to by `a` is equal to -33. To fix it:

```
if (*a == -33)
    *a = 26;
```

You just dereference the pointer to compare it's real value to -33.

Answer (score -1):

I would write the function like

```
void func( int *a )
{
    if ( *a == -33 )
        *a = 26;
    else if ( *a == -19 )
        *a = 27;
}
```

As for your function then it seems there is a typo. Instead of

```
if (a == -33)
```

there has to be

```
if (*a == -33)
```

Comment: @shekhar suman I am sure that my answer differs from others.

Comment: No,the gyst remains the same, whatever priority you give inner-statements to!!!

Comment: Whatever you may assume NOW,but the fact isn't gonna change...